# Why does my firewall block outgoing TCP/UDP port 137 ~ 139 + 53 ~ undefined

Tags: firewall, draytek

I've got a Draytek Vigor 2930 router which has a default xNetBios -> DNS which blocks "TCP/UDP, Port: from 137~139 to 53~undefined".

What is this rule, and what is its purpose?

Comment: Are you sure that's not two rules, ie ports 137-139 and port 53?

Comment: You're right. It is two ranges of ports; but they are grouped under the same name (xNetBios -> DNS)